# How to redirect/route to different link upon smaller screen resolution and vice versa?

Tags: reactjs

So, I have to links i.e home(`/`) and mobile(`/mobile`). What I need is to change the route to `/mobile` if the screen resolution is smaller i.e mobile devices. Vice versa if the screen size is bigger such as laptops/desktop.

Its not about having home responsive. just that I am trying to show something different in both views.

motivation is like facebook does i.e adding `m.facebook.com` for mobile devices. but mine is to change route .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a piece of state called e.g. `isMobile` that you toggle between true and false depending on if the viewport is below a certain width.

If you want it to be responsive you could add a listener for the `resize` event and check again when the screen is resized.

**Example**

```
class MyRedirect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isMobile: window.innerWidth <= 768
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.checkIfMobile);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.checkIfMobile);
  }

  checkIfMobile = () => {
    const { isMobile } = this.state;
    const becameMobile = window.innerWidth <= 768;

    if (isMobile !== becameMobile) {
      this.setState({ isMobile: becameMobile });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <Redirect to={this.state.isMobile ? "/mobile" : "/"} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: That would lead to a change of the url even if somebody just resizes the browser window. That is not exactly an interaction that should trigger a redirect. Also you would always be redirected back instantly when pressing the browser back button which is annoying and confusing to the user. I know OP asked for that kind of solution but I'd argue that you can just display something different solely based on `isMobile` without changing the url.

Comment: @trixn It's just a minimal example, since OP didn't specify when the `Redirect` component will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Make a condition in componentDidMount something like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
 
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // mobile 
    if (window.screen.width <= 480) {
      this.props.history.push('/path');
    }
  }
  
  ...
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```